# Use stride to rotate object

Tags: swift, loops, viewdidload

I want to use the stride syntax to rotate a object in stride. The box should go through 3 iterations and rotate 270 degrees. I don’t believe everything some of my code below matches the Syntax by word. Just a FYI.

```
Var box = UIView()

Override func viewdidload(){
Super.viewdidload()

For rotate in Stride(from : 0, to: 3, by +1 ) {

box.transform = box.transform.rotatedby( .pi/2)
}}
```

Swift, Stirde, loop, viewdidload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot use a loop to do that, because the UI will only be updated after the loop finish

you can use UIView.animate to do animation and do recursive to achieve n-times animation

```
func rotateBox(count: Int) {
        if count > 0 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                self.box.transform = self.box.transform.rotated(by: .pi/2)
            }, completion: { _ in
                self.rotateBox(count: count - 1)
            })
        }
    }
```